# QTimer to execute method every second

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm learning Qt and I was reading about Threads, Events and QObjects from Qt wiki, and followed the wiki recommendations on how to handle some work in a while condition but its not working for my specific case. Here's a simple example of what I'm currently trying to achieve.

```
class FooEvents : public FooWrapper {

    public virtual serverTime(..) { std::cout << "Server time event\n"; }
    public virtual connected(..) { std::cout << "Connected event\n"; }
}

class Foo : public QObject {

private:

    FooAPI *client;

public:


    Foo(FooEvents *ev, QObject *parent = 0) : client(new FooApi(ev)) { .. }

private slots:
    void processMessages() {

        if (state is IDLE)              

            reqFooAPiServerTime();

        select(client->fd()+1, ...);

        if (socket is ready for read)

            client.onReceive();

    }
public:
    void connect(...) {

        if (connection) {

            QObject::connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processMessages()));
            timer.start(1000);  // I don't get the output from FooEvents

        }

    }

}
```

This is a very simple but I think it illustrates my case. Why is this not working and what other alternatives to I have to handle this case? Thanks.s

Edit: The processMessages is being called every second but I don't get any output from the events

Comment: We don't understand "what is not working" unless you specify it!

Comment: I can't see how processMessages() relates to the events (FooEvents?)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld . Its part of API I'm using. I have to implement all the events the API provides and when I call an API method it fires the corresponding event through the FooWrapper.

Comment: @sectorzz9: so you've edited the question to say that `processMessage()` is getting called every second.  In that case, there's clearly no problem with the timer.  You need to ask a question about your real problem of not getting "any output from the events".  There no information here about what output you are expecting, and the question's title has nothing to do with your actual problem (since the method is executing every second).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is `timer` declared and defined?

If it's local to `Foo::connect()` it'll be destroyed before it ever has a chance to fire.  Presumably it just needs to be a member object of the `Foo` class.

Also keep in mind that `QObject` provides it's own simple interface to a timer - just override the protected  virtual `timerEvent()` function and call QObject's  `startTimer()` to start getting those timer events. In this case instead of having a slot to receive the timer events, they will just end up at the overridden `timerEvent()` function:

```
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
        processMessages();
    }

public:
    void connect( /* ... */ ) {

            // ... 

            startTimer(1000);
    }
```

Comment: Although the solution is correct I wouldn't recommend to override timerEvent(). Use QTimer instead, it will make the code much cleaner and it's a dedicated interface for timer related actions (ex: setting it's parameters and to control it).

Comment: Viktor: QTimer has an overhead of an extra QObject with it, and also an extra signal-slot connection. Apart from the obvious memory overhead, the direct (non-queued) signal-slot connection overhead is equivalent on my machine to concatenating two 1000 character QStrings together, so it's hardly trivial. Using a QBasicTimer as a placeholder for timerId and active state of the timer is a decent optimization IMHO. I personally use QTimer only for single-shot, rarely firing convenience use. Anything periodic goes via QBasicTimer and is processed in `QObject::timerEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, because processMessages() is not a `SLOT`.

```
 So Declare processMessages() as a private slot and then try.
```

Comment: Its defined as a slot. I forgot to put it in the example.

Comment: Then check whether it is getting inside if(connection) block!.

Comment: It is.I said that in my Edit message. ProcessMessages is being called every second but the events are not getting fired. It works if I call processMessages directly.

Comment: I made the non-slot mistake accidentally. So, this helped me even if it wasn't applicable to @sectorzz9.

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare the timer neither the slot. In the header you must declare:

```
class ... {

  QTimer timer;
  ...
private slots:
  void processMessages();
  ...
};
```

Then remember to make the SIGNAL-SLOT connection and configure the timer:

```
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processMessages()));
timer.setInterval(1000);
timer.start();
```

Also `timer.start(1000);` would be valid...

**ANOTHER POSSIBILITY**

Other possibility would be to use the timer associated with each Q_OBJECT and overload the `timerEvent`:

```
class ... {
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
  ...
};
```

Then you must implement the timer event as this:

```
void MyClass::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) {
  processMessages();
}
```

And you can configure the timer with a simple call to `startTimer(1000);`