# Qt C++ Run code every second

Tags: c++, qt

I need to check a conditional every second and then run function. Executing is asynchronous so it won't make any problems. Can I call function somewhere in loop? I would get time since program started and check if second passed. Where can i find main loop? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `QTimer`.

Comment: Be careful of the side-effects of the answer you accepted: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Did you even try searching? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287550/how-to-call-a-function-after-every-15-seconds-using-qt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850485/qt-c-run-code-every-second

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667689/qtimer-to-execute-method-every-second http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710255/how-to-call-a-function-every-second-which-updates-qt-widget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091664/qt-how-to-loop-a-method-every-second-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556315/polling-a-variable-in-qt-once-every-second http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786109/how-to-call-a-function-periodically-in-qt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a QTimer can solve this:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
timer->setInterval(1000); //Time in milliseconds
//timer->setSingleShot(false); //Setting this to true makes the timer run only once
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [=](){
    //Do your stuff in here, gets called every interval time
});
timer->start(); //Call start() AFTER connect
//Do not call start(0) since this will change interval
```

In addition (and since there has been an argument about the insecurity of lambda functions on target object lifetime) one can of course connect this to a slot in another object:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, anotherObjectPtr, &AnotherObject::method);
```

Please be aware that this method should not have parameters, since the timeout signal is also defined without parameters.

Comment: Woah! It's perfect! Haven't thought of such a simple solution. Using qt since yesterday and it's a beast!

Comment: Be very careful with this and don't recommend it to noobies! Using lambdas with `QObject::connect()` is not a problem-free toy! There's no automatic disconnection when the target object is destroyed. Refer to this: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Since there is `this` as context it gets disconnectd just fine.

Comment: One more question - what does [=] mean? Can I change it with functionName()?

Comment: @SebastianSzczepański  I edited the answer to reflect the second possibility with connecting to another object, could also be `this` of course.

Comment: @SebastianSzczepański `[=]` cannot be changed to a function name. It means that you capture locale variables by value. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Comment: How can I call function then?

Comment: @SebastianSzczepański Benjamin is just saying, you cannot replace the = with a function, but you can connect to a class method with the second option. If you insist on calling a non-connectable function you can just call this within the lambda functor.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I've Got it now